# ejabberd : replace mnesia with mysql

Tags: ejabberd, mnesia

Is there any way to setup mysql in place of mnesia. any help on this is much appreciated.  Everything for me went on fine. Also I need to archive the history text.

Thanks in advance
Abraham

Answer (score 3):

Check out these links:

http://www.ndl.kiev.ua/content/mod_archive_odbc-release
(Skip the first part about the erlang driver) https://support.process-one.net/doc/display/MESSENGER/Using+ejabberd+with+MySQL+native+driver
http://www.ejabberd.im/ejabberd-modules

I sucesfully setup message archiving on a windows machine after some work, but still need to document the process...

The basic process is get the mod_archive_odbc files from the ejabberd SVN as described in the first link. Compiel the .erl file and put the .beam file in your lib//ebin directory. (For windows binary installs, put the .erl file into the /bin directory of your ejabberd installation and run (third link):

```
erlc -I includes/ejabberd/include mod_<name>.erl
```

After you place the .beam file, you should follow the directions for setting up mysql native DB, run the mod_archive_odbc_mysql.sql script on your mysql ejabberd DB, configure e-jabberd and then restart the server. (Note: if you don't migrate the mnesia data, you will have to manually re-create the admin user.)

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can. Read **[here](https://support.process-one.net/doc/display/MESSENGER/Using+ejabberd+with+MySQL+native+driver)**.

Comment: Hey thanks for your help.  Yes, I think 50% it was helpful .. and I am yet to get a reply for 2nd part.

Comment: I know this is more than 4 years old answer, but I downvoted because there's no additional explanation in your answer besides a broken link.